# Unzipping and reading a .gz (Gzip file) in C#

Tags: c#

Below is the method where I am reading a csv file from an azure blob container and later calling a function to copy the contents in a tabular storage.

Now my requirement has bit changed and now .csv file will be compressed to .gz file in the blob container. I would like to know, how can I modify the below code so that I can read .gz file , decompress it and then pass the contents as I am already passing

```
public async Task<string> ReadStream(string BlobcontainerName, string fileName, string connectionString)
{    
    var contents = await DownloadBlob(BlobcontainerName, fileName, connectionString);
    string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(contents.ToArray());
    return data;
}
```

```
foreach (var files in recFiles)// recFiles are list of CSV files
{
    string data = await ReadStream(containerName, files.Name, connectionString);}
```

```
public async Task<MemoryStream> DownloadBlob(string containerName, string fileName, string connectionString)
{
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
       
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
    CloudBlobClient serviceClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    CloudBlobContainer container = serviceClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
    CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
    if (blob.Exists())
    {
        using (memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            await blob.DownloadToStreamAsync(memoryStream);
        }
    }
    return memoryStream;
}
```

Comment: [GZipStream Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.gzipstream?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: How do i pas the file name here in the above class, it takes path and output will be a stream of data or uncompresed csv file

Comment: Use a MemoryStream, e.g. `using (var ms = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes("File Path"))) using (var gZip = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Decompress))`. Unless you already have a GZipStream there. Write to a new MemoryStream to decode in memory or a FileStream to decode into a file.

Comment: var content is of MemoryStream type.

Comment: Show us `DownloadBlob` method.

Comment: updated with DownloadBlob

Comment: When posting code on Stack Overflow, please use the preview and ask yourself whether that's how you'd want to see the code in a code review etc. I doubt that it's indented like that in your actual code, so please edit your post to make it as presentable as possible.

Comment: i always do that, and I remove some sensitive information from code and thats why you might see some indention mismatch, but overall I see code to be well understood in terms of format

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
public async Task<MemoryStream> DownloadBlob(string containerName, string fileName, string connectionString)
{
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
    CloudBlobClient serviceClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    CloudBlobContainer container = serviceClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
    CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);

    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

    if (blob.Exists())
    {
        using (var gZipStream = new GZipStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
            await blob.DownloadToStreamAsync(gZipStream);
        }
    }
    return memoryStream;
}
```